# Azure Function App Build Error - Multiple Assemblies with Equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, msbuild, azure-functions

I have not touched my Azure functions in several months.  I came back yesterday and made changes which I then pushed to Github.  The CI integration failed to build my changes however, because of the error below:

```
CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'D:\home\site\repository\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll' and 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [D:\home\site\repository\DataModel\DataModel.csproj]
```

It seems like maybe this library now exists on the server by default now, so there's a conflict when it tries to load it again via Nuget.  The problem is, we obviously still need to reference the Nuget package in the project for our development machines to download it.

However, if this were the case, it seems like it would be a very common scenario but I found no other reports of this in the context of Azure Functions. So, I'm wondering if it's related to a recent change, or there's a unique situation afoot.

**UPDATE:**
Unfortunately, never understood or resolved the error or issue. The workaround was not reasonable, but I only had one big function app, so did it and it's over now.  If you have many function apps with this error, I'm sorry.

The workaround was to follow the advice of @david-ebbo and effectively recreate my entire Function App.  I also had to fully recreate all my shared class libraries including my test projects because of new compatibility issues.  Overall, the new paradigm here is really looking good, and I attribute the excessive pain of this situation to working with multiple new and disruptive techs at the same time. Azure Functions + Visual studio + a .NET revolution.  It took me about 3 hours to go and convert all my function.json files to method annotations, and move classes around, and then recreate the whole structure. It as very frustrating with a lot of trial and error, and I'm effectively still limited to only using .NET standard class libraries, which is an issue with a workaround for me.

@david-ebbo , please comment on my new issue if you don't mind.
[Azure Function CI Build Error - Cannot create a file when that file already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743877)

Comment: What is the nature of your project? Are you using the new VS 2017 functions tooling or something else? Note that there was temporary tooling in VS 2015 which involved .csx files and is no longer supported. The new tooling uses compiled .cs files.

Comment: Hey there David, no we got away from .csx files in january. We were early form of precompiled functions basically using this technique:  https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/05/03/precompiled-azure-functions-revisited/

Comment: Note that as of yesterday, new updated VS 2017 has built in support for Function Apps (before that it was only in VS 2017 Preview). Could you give that a try?

Comment: Yes that's very exciting and I plan on using it for my next function app.  Are you suggesting I recreate my entire functionapp structure into a new project just as a "maybe it fixes it" test (note, it's fairly large)?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what's wrong with yours, but generally, the workflow described in the blog you point to was a workaround to get compiled Functions going when there was no official tooling. I would suggest at least installing the new tooling and playing with it to get a sense of it, then determine how hard it would be to convert. Going forward, you'll get better support with the new project type.

Comment: So, it seems I'm currently, I'm the only one reporting this issue then.  Looks like I'll have to give that a try.  Although, TBH, I actually preferred our current project structure and behavior in VS to some of the preview tooling I saw a few months ago.  Will let you know how it goes.