# Azure Function CI Build Error - Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-functions, kudu

This issue is pretty straightforward, the functionapp fails to build with this one error.  I found it interesting that it's stopping on the copy of a .pdb file.  I've stopped and restarted the function app and ran "sync", no improvement.

```
"D:\home\site\repository\API.Routing\API.Routing.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild target) -> 
  D:\home\.nuget\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.0\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(26,5): error MSB3677: Unable to move file "D:\home\site\repository\API.Routing\bin\Release\net461\\API.Routing.pdb" to "D:\home\site\repository\API.Routing\bin\Release\net461\\bin\API.Routing.pdb". Cannot create a file when that file already exists. [D:\home\site\repository\API.Routing\API.Routing.csproj]
```

Comment: One [known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4686f217-f86f-4a44-8d1b-2b226de78344/github-continuous-deployment?forum=AzureFunctions) but this looks different. Can you give more info about the kind of Function app you're deploying? e.g. was it built using the just-released VS 2017 tooling?

Comment: Yes, I created the function app from scratch after updating VS and using the new azure function project workflow.  The solution contains about 8 Netstandard2 class libraries, and 5-6 projects created by doing  "new -> Unit Test Project" in VS.  For those test projects, I had to manually change targeting from 4.6 to 4.6.1.

Comment: Then it's interesting that you don't quite see the same issue. Anyway, we need to address that primary issue first. If you can [share a repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue) that shows your issue, we can test that as well.

Comment: I'll try to slowly remove pieces of it until there's nothing left.  It will either work, or i can copy paste to a public repo.

Comment: That's how it's done! :)

Comment: An update to the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package (v1.0.1) was released this afternoon. I just installed the update, and now Kudu can build my project.  First I'm grateful, second, amazed becaused the current chat in the github issues for the package are about 1.0.0 alpha6, and suddenly there's a 1.0.1 released?  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/  In any case, Kudos to a fast feedback and patch cycle!!  Thanks david, u guys do great work.

Comment: Yes we pushed that package today as part of the solution, but we also need a Kudu update to fix the other issue people are hitting, which you are not hitting. In case you're curious, your issue relates to the double slashes you see in the error, which the new package fixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions nuget package in my project to v1.0.1, pushed the change to GIT, and now Azure Functions builds my project.

Comment: I was getting an error `The "Move" task failed unexpectedly.` (`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800700A1): The specified path is invalid.`) when the `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild` target was trying to copy pdb files. Updating `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.1` also fixed this error for me. Thanks!